# express.js can not get url's hash segment directly?

Tags: express

> ```
> express provide some simple access to request url, as request.query, request.body ...
> ```
>
> ```
> must i use
> ```
>
> url.parse(request.originalUrl).hash.slice(1)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Browser doesn't send hash part of url to the server, so express.js cannot know about it.