# Redirect with Express using Angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

If i go to `http://localhost:3000` to start my project and I'm not logged in, it will go to `http://localhost:3000/login`, but i want it to go to `http://localhost:3000/#/login`.  is there any way to do this unless i redirect in the angular front end?  or am i doing this wrong?

if i could do this in the backend in express it would be ideal

My Angular Routing File

```
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/app',
    templateUrl: '/layout'
})
.state('app.dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: '/dashboard',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'Dashboard',
        description: ''
    }
})
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: '/login',
    ncyBreadcrumb: {
        label: 'Login'
    }
})
```

My Express Routing File

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    return res.redirect('/login');  //this goes to login but doesn't load properly
    //return res.redirect('/#/login');  //does not work
}

router.get('/', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    return res.render('index');
});
```

EDIT: i added this in response to @jiajianrong

```
router.get('/#/login', function (req, res) {
    return res.render('login');
});
```

and changed isLoggedIn function to go to:

```
return res.redirect('/#/login')
```

but it says that it's erroring saying too many redirects cus it's not finding it.

EDIT 2:

I'm sorry i'm not sure if i understand what you're trying to say?  right now for instance .. if there was no `isLoggedIn` check, it would go to the dashboard automatically where the url is `http://localhost:3000/#/app/dashboard` due to this line of code here i believe?:

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard');

but i have no route in my Express side for `/app/dashboard` specifically.  my dashboard routing that already works properly is as so:

```
router.get('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
    return res.render('dashboard');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `router.get()`, you are matching `'/'`.
The isLoggedIn redirects response to `/#/login`, which also matches the same `'/'`, then you get a circle.

The reason why `res.redirect('/login');` works is you have a router dealing with '/login', which stops the router chain going to `router.get('/', isLoggedIn, fn)`

So you need to add a new router rule to deal with `/#/login`

**Updated**

---

After research I found

[Browser doesn't send hash part of url to the server, so express.js cannot know about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453135/express-js-can-not-get-urls-hash-segment-directly)

Which I verified with a demo test by visiting `http://127.0.0.1:3000/aaa#/login`

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
```

This code shows `url_parts` to be

```
{
  "protocol":null,
  "slashes":null,
  "auth":null,
  "host":null,
  "port":null,
  "hostname":null,
  "hash":null,
  "search":"",
  "query":{},
  "pathname":"/aaa",
  "path":"/aaa",
  "href":"/aaa"
}
```

So there is no a right choose matching `#hash`.
So in your case you should add a real path in url and then match it, such as `http://127.0.0.1:3000/homepage/#/login`

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your comment. Could you please explain more?

Comment: i edited the original post in response to your answer but I can't get it to work.  is what I edited in my original post what you were trying to tell me to do?

Comment: @user1189352  I updated my post, please check.  Now I think the standard is to use pathname, rather than hash in `window.location` to track router. More info about hash please see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#section-4

Comment: sorry just turned off the laptop will check tomorrow at work.  thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your main route is **`/`**, and it render main `index.(html/ejs)`.

Now angular ui-router has 3 routes like.

```
/abc
/xyz
/abc/xyz
```

So you need to create **4 routes in express**, which renders `index.(html/ejs)`.

**Or**
If you ui-router contains `app` or other common name as path.

```
/app/abc
/app/xyz
/app/*
```

Then check regex of URL in express router or middleware, if it contains `app` then render `index.(html/ejs)`.

Comment: made an "EDIT2" for you.  still not sure what i should be doing to get this to work

Comment: Above solution works if you're user html5 push state true (like ex. http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard), If you're using `#` then just make one route with `/` and load `index.html`, Once it'll load `/#/app/dashboard` will render via angular ajax

Comment: i'm sorry i still don't understand how to fix the issue i'm talking about unfortunately.  maybe you can edit your response to show me how exactly

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to remove `/#` by enabling HTML 5 mode.

From the [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

In your router file, you could do:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: true
    });

    $stateProvider
    .state
    ...

});
```

**index.html**

```
<base href="/">
```

Now you can access your paths without `/#` and no need to change the server side.

Comment: sweet gonna try this in a bit will let u know, thank you